# python3: Using ternary operator in map, it will return None

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

### For python 2.7.13

```
>>> lst_ = [1]
>>> map(lambda x, y: x + y if y else 1, lst_, lst_[1:])
[1]
```

### For python 3.6.1

```
>>> lst_ = [1]
>>> list(map(lambda x, y: x + y if y else 1, lst_, lst_[1:]))
[]
```

### Two Questions:

- I want to know why the python2 return the correct result, but python3 return None
- How should I modify the code with python3 to return the correct result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a change to the functionality of the `map()` function (together with the change to becoming an iterator). Because the inputs are now *iterators*, `map()` has been updated to follow the same behaviour as `zip()`, and not pad shorter inputs with `None` values.

Compare the [documentation for `map()` in Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

> If one iterable is shorter than another it is assumed to be extended with `None` items.

with the [Python 3 version](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

> With multiple iterables, the iterator stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted.

You can use [`itertools.zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) together with [`itertools.starmap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to get the Python 2 behaviour again:

```
from itertools import starmap, zip_longest

starmap(lambda x, y: x + y if y else 1, zip_longest(lst_, lst_[1:]))
```

`zip_longest()` has the added advantage that you can now specify what value to use as a filler; as an example, you can set it to `0`:

```
starmap(lambda x, y: x + y, zip_longest(lst_, lst_[1:], fillvalue=0))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import starmap, zip_longest
>>> lst_ = [1]
>>> list(starmap(lambda x, y: x + y if y else 1, zip_longest(lst_, lst_[1:])))
[1]
>>> list(starmap(lambda x, y: x + y, zip_longest(lst_, lst_[1:], fillvalue=0)))
[1]
```

Comment: Now I think I know ! Thanks!